# How can I use django's IF templatetag parsing in a custom tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

As an example use case, lets say I want to create a tag like this

```
{% linkif (section=='main') url %}Text{% endlinkif %}
```

to avoid verbiage like

```
{% if section == 'main' %}
   <a href="{{ url }}">text</a>
{% else %}
    text
{% endif %}
```

or

```
 {% if section == 'main' %}<a href="{{ url }}">{% endif %}text{% if section == 'main' %}</a>{% endif %}
```

both of which involve repeating yourself.

If the expression evaluates to true, outputs a link to url surrounding the text, otherwise just output the text.

How would you evaluate the expression using django's IF tag logic? Is there a function to call that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would put it this way (and css will be happier too)

```
<a href="{% if section == 'main' %}{{ url }}{% else %}#{% endif %}">text</a>
```

Comment: That was just an example use case - the question is really about how to evaluate expressions in arguments for template tags, in general.